# Custom CSS not working with CSS Bundling for Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, cssbundling-rails

Playing around with Rails 7 and I don't understand why my custom CSS is not working.

I built new rails app with flag for Bootstrap, which is working fine (CSS and JS, tested with bootstrap modal). These are my default config files:

*application.js*

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

*application.bootstrap.scss*

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.1.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.23",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "stimulus": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
}
```

And I can built CSS in `/builds/application.css`

---

Now I want to add custom CSS. This is my process:

1. Added new file `stylesheets/custom.css`, with css:

```
    .my-class {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #00eb00;
    }
```

2. Add import to application.bootstrap.scss

   `@import "custom";`
3. `yarn run build:css`
4. And now I can see `.my-class` in `builds/application.css`

But when I try to use id in HTML, no CSS is added. Why? Should I place it somewhere else?

**EDIT:**  I got it running, but only when I run manually rails assets:precompile and then bin/dev.
Why do I need to precompile every time I change something?

Answer (score 9):

In a fresh rails 7 app (with `css=bootstrap`), here's what I did to get custom css styles:

1. Uncomment `gem 'sass-rails` in Gemfile, then bundle install (more info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514604/rails-5-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-sass-when-deploying-to-heroku))
2. Create a new css file in app/assets/stylesheets and name it example.css.scss
3. Add this line to app/assets/config/manifest.js:

```js
//= link example.css
```

4. Wherever you need access to those styles, include this tag

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "example", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

5. Start your server with `bin/dev` instead of `rails server`
6. Everything should work (a nice test is to include this in your example.css.scss file and H1s should turn green)

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

#### Resource

- Very helpful video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYr8yn7yRKw&t=4m45s)

---

#### A separate problem

I also got this error (when I googled it, I arrived at my own answer here!):

```
The asset 'application.css' was not found in the load path.
```

pointing to this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

In this case, running [`yarn run build:css`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76387886/5783745) was the solution. When I tried that I saw:

```
yarn run build:css
rbenv: sass: command not found

The `sass' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.7.7
  3.0.3
  3.2.2
```

so I ran `npm install sass`, then tried `yarn run build:css` again and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered this problem and noticed both JavaScript and CSS are not recompiled after changes.
If you have `gem jsbundling-rails` included in your gemfile, check out https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails for more details and how-tos.
Run `yarn run build:css` to recompile the CSS assets.

I prefer using `./bin/dev` to start my local server and monitor both JavaScript and CSS updates.

Comment: I prefer running these in separate docker containers with docker-compose.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add new file **stylesheets/custom.css** and create new css class.
2. Add import to application.bootstrap.scss  **@import "custom";**
3. then run `yarn run build:css` to recompile the CSS assets.
4. Now you can see custom-class in **builds/application.css** alongside with bootstrap css

Run the local server to `./bin/dev` to automatically build the CSS and JavaScript updates.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer running the app using foreman, with command `$ bin/dev` this way it automatically compiles the scss files.

Answer (score -2):

It worked for me if I added

```
//= link custom.css
```

to app/assets/config/manifest.js

And I didn't add @import "custom"; to application.bootstrap.scss